# Possible reporting error in recurring transactions

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

I am using Drupal 7.58, CiviCRM 4.7.30, eWay Recurring version 1.2, Webform version 7.x-4.16 and Webform CiviCRM Integration version 7.x-4.19+40-dev.

I have observed discrepancies in reporting when membership payments are made in instalments. Assume a total payment of $277 made in two monthly instalments of $138.50. The first payment of $138.50 is correctly processed in the eWay payment gateway but the transaction in the book keeping report shows a value of $277.00. When the second instalment is processed it is correctly recorded as $138.50 in eWay and in the book keeping report.

The attached images show:

- the contribution details from the contact's contribution tab
- the line item from the book keeping report for the initial instalment
- the line item from the book keeping report for the second instalment
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Martin - we are looking at some Partial payment issues on another project - do you want to ping me about our progress on that in case it overlaps for you.

Comment: I think this was the JIRA ticket we were looking at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21700

Comment: hmm maybe unrelated

Comment: If there is anything I can do to shed light on the issue let me know.

Comment: Is anyone interested in this problem and able to comment on it.